# Permission denied when executing a RUN command in DockerFile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am seeing a Permission Denied error when trying to run a `npx` command in DockerFile.

The command is:

`RUN $(npx cypress cache path)`

```
Step 13/15 : RUN $(npx cypress cache path)
 ---> Running in 665c47c96bdb
/bin/sh: 1: /root/.cache/Cypress: Permission denied
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c $(npx cypress cache path)' returned a non-zero code: 126
Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream
```

The full `DockerFile` is:

```
FROM cypress/base:10
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY app ./app
COPY serve.json ./

COPY cypress.json cypress ./
COPY cypress ./cypress

ENV CI=1

RUN npm ci

RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify

RUN $(npx cypress cache path)
```

How can I `sudo` run this command, in order to obtain its output please?

Many thanks

Comment: can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Included. Thank you!

Comment: you're running as root, you don't need `sudo`

Comment: What do you want that `RUN` statement to do?  How would you run it outside of Docker?  (From what you've shown, I'd expect the exact same error: `cypress cache path` looks to print out a directory name, and `$(...)` tries to run it as a command.)

Comment: I'm expecting it to out put the cache path, which are along the lines of `/root/.cache/Cypress`. This command works outside of a Docker container.